# Creating Modal Object need help dealing with isVisible state

Tags: react-native, state, react-native-modal

I am currently trying to create a Modal object using react-native-modal like this

```
const ModalExample = (props) => {
    return (
        <Modal isVisible={props.isVisible}>
               <Text>Hello!</Text>
               <Button title="Hide modal" onPress={this.setModalVisibility} />
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

The problem is that the onPress is supposed to change the state from true to false but doesn't have access to the state within the class. 
Here is the button that initializes the modal and how i'm calling the object:

```
<Button title="Show modal" onPress={this.setModalVisibility} />
<ModalExample isVisible={this.state.modalVisible}/>
```

and just  incase here is my setModalVisibility that is within the class

```
setModalVisibility = () =>{
     this.setState({modalVisible: !this.state.modalVisible})
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function as well,

```
<ModalExample isVisible={this.state.modalVisible} setModalVisibility={this.setModalVisibility}/>
```

Call that function in modal,

```
const ModalExample = (props) => {
    return (
        <Modal isVisible={props.isVisible}>
             <Text>Hello!</Text>
             <Button title="Hide modal" onPress={props.setModalVisibility} />
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

**Note:** You don't have access to `this` in functional component.

Comment: If it helps, please mark it as the solution and close the question. thanks!